# Trapping focus in react-bootstrap dropdowns and popovers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am working on some accessibility changes, and I would like to trap the focus inside a popover/dropdown if a popover/dropdown is open.

I am using `react-bootstrap`, and I'd like to know if there is a way to do it that's supported by `react-bootstrap`.

I have seen the documentation and I was not able to find anything in the react-bootstrap documentation. The modals already trap focus, but dropdowns and popovers don't.

I however can use some other package, like focus trap etc, to do that, which I tried on a popover and that seemed to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/focus-trap-js
There is an explanation how to use it in React using hooks